# d3 read csv with d3.map and d3 queue() function

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, mapping

I want to mapping to data city to each province.

This is my sample csv data. (a.k.a 'city.csv')

```
citycode,province,name
3704051,ProvinceA,city1
3704052,ProvinceA,city2
3704054,ProvinceA,city3
3704062,ProvinceA,city4
3704056,ProvinceA,city5
3704058,ProvinceA,city6
3704059,ProvinceA,city7
3704060,ProvinceB,city8
3704061,ProvinceB,city9
3704063,ProvinceB,city10
3702011,ProvinceC,city11
3702012,ProvinceC,city12
```

After mapping, I want to get all stuffs with province.
For example, If I put the value, 'ProvinceA', return '3704051', '3704052' ..etc

First, I have to read data like this.

```
var popByProvinceName = d3.map()

queue()
  .defer(d3.json, "municipalities.json")
  .defer(d3.csv, "city.csv", function(d) {
    d.citycode = +d.citycode;
    popByProvinceName.set(d.province, + d.citycode);
  }).await(ready);

function ready(error, data1) {
  console.log(popByProvinceName.get("ProvinceA");
}
```

is return only one citycode by province.

```
 3704059
```

How can I fix it? please help!

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the value with each iteration.  You need to push them into an array:

```
queue()
  //.defer(d3.json, "municipalities.json")
  .defer(d3.csv, "city.csv", function(d) {
    d.citycode = +d.citycode;
    // first time we've seen province
    if (!popByProvinceName.has(d.province)) {
      popByProvinceName.set(d.province, []);
    }
    // get the array and add to it
    popByProvinceName.get(d.province).push(d.citycode);
  }).await(ready);
```

Full [code](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZyFdL4vM8H75swWL4DMs?p=preview).

---

An alternate and slightly cleaner way to do this would be to use [d3.nest](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#nest) in your ready function:

```
function ready(error, data1) {
  var nest = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.province; })
    .rollup(function(r){
      return r.map(function(d){
        return +d.citycode;
      });
    })
    .entries(data1);
```

Full [code](http://plnkr.co/edit/cP3bRbnzvPVVOWf3X3Yv?p=preview).